# Как сохранить путь файла в базе ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

```
 public class Files
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Поле не может быть пустым")]
        [Display(Name = "Приложить файл")]
        public string Path { get; set; }

        public int TasksId { get; set; }
        public virtual Tasks Tasks { get; set; }
    }


public ActionResult Edit(Tasks tasks, IFormFile uploadedFile)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (uploadedFile != null)
                {
                    // путь к папке Files
                    string path = "/files/" + uploadedFile.FileName;
                    // сохраняем файл в папку Files в каталоге wwwroot
                    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(_appEnvironment.WebRootPath + path, FileMode.Create))
                    {
                        uploadedFile.CopyTo(fileStream);
                    }
                    db.Tasks.Update(tasks);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View();
        }
```

Как мне сохранить путь файла в базе в поле Path(модель Files)?

Comment: Собственно, почему у вас  db.Tasks, если должно быть  db.Files?

Comment: Как string path передать в модель (tasks)